# Not seeing the entries in control panel

Tags: entries, migration, siteurl

We recently moved the site from one domain to another domain (development to staging). I am able to login to control panel and see the fields and sections but when I go to entries, i dont see any entry in there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you logged in as an Admin?

Comment: Any errors in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple language set? If yes, check that you're selecting the right language on the entries drop-down.

[image]